# How can I find my steam ID?

Tags: steam

How can I find my steam ID?

I haven't bought any games; I am playing a free one.
Is the ID only created if I buy a game?

Comment: When was the last time you saw your ID?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Get your SteamID 64-bit**

*Method 1*

Login to Steam using a web broswer.

Once logged click on your profile and add `?xml=1` to browser url address

`http://steamcommunity.com/id/<yourname>/?xml=1`
or
`http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<yourprofilenumber>/?xml=1` (if you have not set a public username yet)

*Method 2*

Open this file `<Steam Installation Path>\config\loginusers.vdf` in notepad.

You'll receive a long XML file but you can look at tag  at the beggining. It contains your 64-bit SteamID.

```
<profile>  
<steamID64>7234567890123456</steamID64>
```

**Get your SteamID 32-bit**

Using a simple formula you can also build your Steam 32-bit ID similar to `STEAM_X:Y:Z` (e.g. `STEAM_1:0:12345678`) starting from Steam 64-bit ID

```
Z = (SteamID64 - 76561197960265728)  / 2
Y = SteamID64 % 2
X = 1 if profile is public / 0 if profile is private
```

Comment: You can also load your profile as XML to get your data. Example, http://steamcommunity.com/id/neon1024?xml=1

Answer (score 8):

If you have registered an account with Steam, you have a steam ID. This ID number, however, is *not* the same as your account name, *nor* is it any nickname you may choose to set.

The Steam Support site has a pretty thorough [step by step instruction](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1558-QYAX-1965).

> How can I find my SteamID?
>
> SteamID refers to your Steam account's
> unique numeric identifier. The
> instructions below will help you find
> your SteamID - for assistance with the
> Steam Community, please see the Steam
> Community topic.
>
> - Launch any Valve multiplayer game.
> - Click Options.
> - Select the Keyboard tab.
> - Click the Advanced button.
> - Check the box labeled Enable Developer Console.
> - Click Apply and then click OK.
> - Join or create a server.
> - From the menu screen, press the tilde ~ key - typically in the
>   upper left hand corner of the keyboard
>   to load the Console.
> - Type status into the console text field and press the Enter key.
>   Your SteamID will be displayed next to your nickname in the console window. SteamID example:
>   STEAM_0:1:1234567

Comment: this is the only way? I don't have any Valve (first party, like TF2, Half-Life, etc) games installed!

Comment: @JeffAtwood - Just look at your profile page.  There isn't a need to use any third-party service or launch any Steam purchase, just view your profile, within Steam.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative [Steam ID Finder](http://www.vacbans.com). It can do more things than just finding a Steam ID. It can also estimate the age of private accounts and keeps track of how many people have searched for each Steam profile.

Full disclosure: I am the owner of http://www.vacbans.com

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Apparently this site gives you info on private accounts, which some members of the community are arguing is not a good idea to promote.

Comment: I'm the creator of VacBans.com. I poured my sweat and blood into this project. The developer page on the Valve site explains how to use Steam IDs to determine the age of accounts. It's no secret. It's common knowledge in the gaming community. People will judge people based on the length of their steam ID with or without my site. I just make that judgement more accurate. :)

Comment: @user51895 Full disclosure is important. :)

Answer (score -1):

the easiest way to find steam id - is to open [Steam Id Finder](http://steamidfinder.ru/).
Input anything you know (even profile url or dotabuff url) - it will show you all public details about that account.

Comment: This adds nothing not covered by user51895's answer.