# Where did my screenshots go?

Tags: steam

I was playing a Steam game yesterday and remember taking a Steam screenshot with the <kbd>F12</kbd> key. I distinctly remember the "shutter" sound and the Steam popup which appeared with the small version of the image. But checking the screenshots section of my Steam profile today, I can only see old screenshots for that game, and nothing from yesterday.

Where did my screenshots go? Did I lose them completely?

Some notes:

1. I've looked under the "all" tab of the screenshots section, to make sure I'm not missing anything.
2. I've clicked the "Update" button, it didn't change anything.
3. This game certainly supports this feature - I took screenshots this way in the past.
4. I've checked the regular screenshot folder for the game - the one where the screenshots go to if you just click <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> - but it didn't contain any recent screenshots.
5. Steam Client details: Built Sep 8 2011, at 13:50:04, API version v012, Steam package version 1675.
6. System is Windows 7 64-bit.
7. Game in question, if it makes any difference, is Civilization V.

Comment: Check: "\steam\userdata\<userid>\760\remote\<appID>\screenshots\" Is it located there? Note: AppID for Civ V is 8930

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You haven't uploaded the screenshot yet, so it won't be on your profile. in Steam's main menu, click on "View" -> "Screenshots".

[image: View Menu with Screenshots highlighted]

You can then pick the game to show at the top, and that will show all the screenshots you've ever made in that game, uploaded or not.

Comment: "Screenshots" is now available from Steam's main menu, under View > Screenshots. It's no longer in the tray icon's right click menu.

Answer (score 14):

In the event that you cannot open Steam (perhaps you are accessing the screenshots from another file system), with some digging you can find the actual image files on your computer.

On a **Windows install** of Steam, use the following path:

```
C:\Program Files\Steam\userdata\[USER_ID]\760\remote\[GAME_ID]\screenshots
```

The `USER_ID` and `GAME_ID` will be string of numbers, and vary depending on what your Steam ID is and what game you are seeking your screenshots for. For further reading on how to find those fields, see:

- **USER ID:** [How can I find my Steam ID?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25786/how-can-i-find-my-steam-id)
- **GAME ID:** [How can I find the ID for a game on Steam?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/149837/how-do-i-find-the-id-for-a-game-on-steam)

Comment: That's "Program Files (x86)" rather than "Program Files", but thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to the game where you took your screenshot.
2. Press Shift key and the Tab key to go to the Steam menu.
3. Go to the screenshot manager and click "SHOW ON DISK".
4. Voilà! You have your screenshots where you want them!

Comment: In the screenshot manager, the _"SHOW ON DISK"_ button doesn't seem to appear when you are in-game, however, the button does show up in the same manager after the game has quit.

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu I found them under

```
~/.local/share/Steam/userdata/<user id?>/760/remote/<game id?>/screenshots
```

---

The directory layout is pretty unintelligible to me, I would recommend like others have, opening the screenshot tool, from the main window that's:

(File Menu) <kbd>View</kbd> -> <kbd>Screenshots</kbd>

Select a game and "**Show on Disk**"

Answer (score -2):

I found mine in:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\oblivion

For posting to Steam, you should use F12 rather than Print Screen to take them.

Comment: But I'm asking about the F12 screenshot here, not the game-specific screenshots.