# Where are screenshots saved in EU4?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I took a screenshot in Europa Universalis 4 but I can't seem to find the location of the image file! Where is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two kinds of screenshot in this game.

You can either take the usual Steam screenshots with <kbd>F12</kbd>. This is explained [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30051/where-did-my-screenshots-go).

It is also possible to take a screenshot of the whole map with <kbd>F10</kbd>. In this case, the file will be located in `Documents\Paradox Interactive\Europa Universalis IV\Screenshots`.

Answer (score 4):

On linux the folder is `~/.local/share/Paradox Interactive/Europa Universalis IV/Screenshots`